# capture property binding in angular

Tags: angular

I want to capture the [src] property binding to modify it with a directive and prepend with a url prefix.

```
<img class="logo" tv-user-content [src]="config.logo" *ngIf="config !== undefined"/>
```

and this directive

```
import { AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tv-user-content]'
})
export class UserContentDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input() src: string;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('src',"myprefix" + this.src);
  }
}
```

is this posible?

Comment: Why not use a pipe?

Comment: It would work in this case, but I wanted to know of to intercept the binding because I maybe make more changes on the element depending on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `src` an input with a setter and add the prefix if it wasn't added yet, to prevent an endless loop:

```
export class UserContentDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  @Input() set src(value: string) {
    if(!value) {
      this.prefixedSrc = null;
    } else {
      if(value.startsWith("myprefix") {
        this.prefixedSrc = value;
      } else {
        this.prefixedSrc = `myprefix${value}`;
      }
    }
  }

  @HostBinding('src') 
  prefixedSrc:string;
}
```

Comment: I knew that I was missing something, I had see the hostbinding but did not think it was the solution. Thanks.

Comment: `el.nativeElement.xxx` is usually frowned upon in Angular, so there are usually ways to avoid it, at least when it is about updating the DOM, much less when it is about reading from the DOM, but in properly build Angular apps the need should be rare.